# How to SELECT and ORDER BY on derived values using Hibernate/JPA criteria. For example, calculated distance with Latitude and Longitude

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, spring-data-jpa

I have a web application which allows users to search for restaurants based on multiple criteria such as; Cuisine, Seating Capacity, BYOB etc
I have new requirements to allow for searching of these restaurants by distance in Miles to the users current location and also to allow for sorting of these restaurants by distance. I want to be able to do this as part of my current searching implementation but I am stuck on how to do this in a single fetch.

My current search implementation involves ORM. I am using Hibernate as my JPA provider and Spring-Data-JPA on MySQL 5.7.
Existing search dynamically uses JPA Criteria and the Spring-Data-JPA Specifications API where I can call findAll(Specification spec, Pageable pageable) or findAll(Specification spec, Sort sort) on my RestaurantRepository interface. This interface extends CrudRepository and JpaSpecificationExecutor.
This makes it easy to add predicates as needed for fields already on the tables in the database. The problem is, distance is a derived value, based on supplied latitude and longitude

I need to be able to do something like this:

```
select r.*, acos(sin(radians([USER_LATITUDE])) * sin(radians(latitude)) + cos(radians([USER_LATITUDE])) * cos(radians(latitude)) * cos(radians(longitude) - (radians([USER_LONGITUDE])))) * 3959 as distance from
restaurant r join town t on r.town_id = t.id join
where r.byob = 'Y' and r.capacity > 200
and distance < [DISTANCE] order by [DISTANCE];
```

In this query, distance is a calculated value, and it's also used in the sort. The supplied values are the users latitude and longitude values and the max distance.

Options I have looked into/considered:

1. Abandon ORMs and use plain JDBC. Will resolve the issue but lose all benefits of ORM.
2. Using Hibernate @Formula but it's not feasible as I can't provide parameters to @Formula. The parameter I would need to provide is the distance.
3. Looked into Hibernate Spatial but it does not support this use case unless I have overlooked something
4. Consider flattening all my data into something like ElasticSearch or SOLR which support distance based lookups but this would be a maintenance nightmare, keeping relational data indexed as it's changed.
5. I have 45k 'Towns' in my database and I considered pre-calculating the distance for all of them with each other. Not really feasible as this would result in 1.8Billion rows.
6. Currently looking into refining the select query with minimum and maximum latitude and longitude using a bounding circle, to then somehow use a native function call in my order by to sort by calculated distance, then when fetching the entities, to use a listener postLoad call to derive the distance in the app again.

If all else fails, I might just have to bite the bullet and do a second lookup using a native query with the SQL I have described above but this would involve a second fetch and would result in a performance hit I do not want.

Can anyone help with suggestions on how I can solve this?

Comment: Another alternative you did not mention was to use a stored procedure and have hibernate call it with the various parameters.  The stored procedure would then return the list of restaurants which are mapped just like a regular query except the stored procedure takes care of applying the distance requirements.

Comment: I could do that but I would still be required to run a separate query for the other criteria. I need to be able to do, distance search AND cuisine type search AND add any other criteria in a single query. That is the problem.