HQL ORDER BY query with adding days to date column
I use spring boot, and I want to add specific days to date column in mysql database on hql query order by clause. But which results error when I tried. I need to get results in the order of adding specific number of days to the date field.
List<SectionInfo> dataList = new ArrayList<>();
Query query = session.createQuery("FROM SectionInfo where active = true and sectionId.id = :sectionId ORDER BY DATE_ADD(auditDate, auditId.auditDays)");
query.setParameter("sectionId", sectionId);
query.setFirstResult(page == 1 ? 0 : calculateOffset(page, maxCount));
query.setMaxResults(maxCount);
dataList = query.list();

Error that I got is as below
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'sectionaud1_.audit_days) limit 20' at line 1
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet

Here auditId.auditDays & auditDate value is different for each row of data. Below are the tables used
public class SectionInfo implements Serializable {

     @Id
     @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
     @Column(name = "id")
     private long id;

     @JoinColumn(name = "section_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
     @OneToOne(optional = false)
     private Section sectionId;

     @JoinColumn(name = "audit_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
     @OneToOne(optional = false)
     private SectionAudit auditId;

     @Column(name="comment")
     private String comment;

     @Column(name = "audit_date")
     @JsonAdapter(DateJsonSerializer.class)
     private Date auditDate;

     public SectionInfo() {
     }
 }

public class SectionAudit implements Serializable {

     @Id
     @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
     @Column(name = "id")
     private long id;

     @Column(name="name")
     private String name;

     @Column(name="audit_days")
     private int auditDays;
}

How to do this correctly. Please help.

Adding the same amount of days to all the rows doesn't change the ordering even if you wouldn't add it. So not sure why you are not just ordering on the date itself.

@M.Deinum It's not same amount of days, auditId.auditDays is a dynamic value which is different for each row.

What is the error you get?

@M.Deinum  You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'sectionaud1_.audit_days) limit 20' at line 1
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet

not sure it's possible, given this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41231631/how-to-select-and-order-by-on-derived-values-using-hibernate-jpa-criteria-for-e
